# Show comments without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I want to show the comment user posts, right after he posts it.I already made the ajax upload the comment, how can i display it to the user, without refreshing? I have this ajax code:

```
  $(".comments input[name='post']").keydown(function (evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.which?evt.which:evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
      var form = $(this).closest("form");
      var container = $(this).closest(".comments");
      var input = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'comment' letnik_id=letnik_id classes_id=classes_id subject_id=subject_id %}",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
          $(input).val("");
          $(input).blur();
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert("Successful comment");
          $(input).val("");
          $(input).blur();
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

This posts the comment. In views.py i save comment:

```
def comment(request, letnik_id, classes_id, subject_id):
try:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        exam_id = request.POST.get('exam_id')
        exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, id=exam_id)
        comment = request.POST.get('post')
        comment = comment.strip()
        if len(comment) > 0:
            instance = ExamComment(
                exam=exam,
                comment=comment,
                comment_user=request.user)
            instance.save()
            return redirect('subject_id', letnik_id=letnik_id, classes_id=classes_id, subject_id=subject_id)
        html = ''
        for comment in exam.get_comments():
            html = '{0}{1}'.format(html, render_to_string('exam_partial_comment.html', {'comment': comment}))
        return HttpResponse(html)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
except Exception:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Also without: `return redirect('subject_id', letnik_id=letnik_id, classes_id=classes_id, subject_id=subject_id)`
this code, i would get error400 and i wouldn`t get success alert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/) function instead of HttpResponse. With JsonResponse, you just pass a dictionary object with the comments you want to update in your page, something like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
if request.method == 'POST':
    #...
    if len(comment) > 0:
        #...saving...
    comments = ExamComment.objects.filter(exams=exams, comment_user=request.user)
    newcomments = {comments:[]}
    for comment in comments:
        newcomments[comments].append(comment) 
    return JsonResponse(newcomments)
else:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

This way there is no rendering involved and you return new (and old) comments back to your template. Next you need to rebuild your comment div (which i don't know the name) after the ajax success:

```
success: function (data) {
      alert("Successful comment");
      $(input).val("");
      $(input).blur();
      var div = document.getElementById('yourCommentDivName');
      newcomments = ''
      for(i;i<data.comments.length;i++){
         newcomments = newcomments + '<p>' + data.comments[i] + '</p>'
      }
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + newcomments;
    }
```

Well that's it. Comments: code is not tested; If you do this kind of stuff a lot, you should look into some javascript libraries which does this out of the box, as react. Steep learning curve, but once you understand it is a life saver; Last thing is, well, avoid this try except stuff. This makes debugging harder, and is bad for your health in the long run. Do this only if you really really have to, which I don`t think is the case.

Hope it helps!

Comment: could i render only the new comment, not all together, as all others would already be rendered?

Comment: Sure! Instead of querying for all comments in the view, just send the new comment back in JsonResponse inside a dictionary, like JsonResponse({comment:comment}). On the ajax success function, drop the for loop and just add the new coment as  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + comment;  Yep, much better this way.

Comment: Thank you so much. But there is a problem. If i down include this: return redirect('subject_id', letnik_id=letnik_id, classes_id=classes_id, subject_id=subject_id) in the view, I dont get success in ajax. Do you happen to know why is that? I get error 400 (bad request), but after refresh the comment gets posted

Comment: So, you are getting bad request probably because the server is finding an error below the `return` line, and then raising an exception which is handled by returning the bad request on the last line. So, get rid of the `try` and using the same code check the error django returns to you.

Comment: OKay that did the trick!
CAn i ask you just one more question? I set JsonResponse({"comment":"Hello"}), how can i display that with ajax in template, lets say in alert?

Comment: Great that worked! The dictionary you pass in Json response is reached in the `data` object on the success function.  So success: `function (data) {
          alert(data.comment);
          
        }` will print Hello in your example.